# How to validate that a string is a valid url in javascript/node.js

Tags: node.js, parsing

I'm writing a kind of CMS-interface system and for some fields a user must input urls of images, links to external sites etc.

I want to check whether a given string is a valid url and does not contain some malicious code, e.g. `str = '"></a><script>alert("You are doomed!");</script><a href="'`

The server is written on node.js. So I tried standard `require('url').parse(str)`. On the above string it returns

```
{ 
  protocol: null,
  slashes: null,
  auth: null,
  host: null,
  port: null,
  hostname: null,
  hash: null,
  search: null,
  query: null,
  pathname: '%22%3E%3C/a%3E%3Cscript%3Ealert(%22You%20are%20doomed!%22);%3C/script%3E%3Ca%20href=%22',
  path: '%22%3E%3C/a%3E%3Cscript%3Ealert(%22You%20are%20doomed!%22);%3C/script%3E%3Ca%20href=%22',
  href: '%22%3E%3C/a%3E%3Cscript%3Ealert(%22You%20are%20doomed!%22);%3C/script%3E%3Ca%20href=%22'
}
```

which may seem suitable because almost all fields are `null`, however it also returns nulls on `str='/myimage.png'` that is a valid url.

Comment: I think you can use the module [valid-uri](https://www.npmjs.com/package/valid-url)